# How can I create a count attribute for instances that will be different for every instance of another class to which they are related?

Tags: rdf, owl, protege, knowledge-graph

I am working in Protege 5.

Class Document is a document (the body).

Class Word is a word (string).

**This is my model now:**

Object property: containsWord-- domain Document, range Word

Data property: occuranceCount-- domain Word, range integer(built in)

**Instead I need something like:**

Object property: Document conatainsWord "x" with count "n".

Where "x" is a word instance and "n" a the number of times that individual is found in the body of a particular Document.

Either each unique document should have attributes describing how many times "x" occurs in them.

**OR**

Each Word "x" should have a list of Document instances in which it appears along with how many times it appears.

Do I really have to make a new instance of a word just so I can count how many times it occurs in each document? (ridiculous waste of space but possible).

Comment: Given that you need a 3-ary but OWL/RDF do only have unary (classes) and binary relations (properties), yes you'll need an intermediate individual. Like `doc1 hasWordOccurence woc1 . woc1 hasWord word1 . woc1 hasOccurence 20 ` - or you use annotations. But just have a lokk at https://www.w3.org/TR/swbp-n-aryRelations/ - you're not the first one asking this

Comment: @UninformedUser thank you for the reference!